# C# How To Sort Two Columns By Hierarchy

Tags: c#, sorting, logic, hierarchy

I am comparing user groups to see what groups are members of other groups.  I then need order them from largest scope to smallest.  An example from any language would be fine.  I know a series of loops would accomplish this but haven't been able to successfully do it.  Here is my example.  I have two lists as follows:

```
 IT          Staff 
 Teacher     Staff 
 Engineer    IT 
 Engineer    Staff
```

We can see that the IT department is a part of staff, Teachers are a part of staff, an engineer is a part of IT and and Engineer is a part of Staff.  I need to end up with something like:

```
 Staff
 IT Teacher
 Engineer
```

It doesn't matter here that Engineer is listed below Teacher and is not part of a teacher group.  I just need to get an order of largest scope to smallest.  Since I know that IT and Teacher are on the same level and Engineer is smaller than IT, IT must also be smaller than Teacher.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.get unique item from both columns:

> - IT
> - Teacher
> - Engineer
> - Staff

2.give each item a starting weight, e.g: 100

> - IT = 100
> - Teacher = 100
> - Engineer = 100
> - Staff = 100

3.for each item, each time it is appeared in the first column (`column[0]`), minus its weight by 1

> - IT = 100 - 1 = 99
> - Teacher = 100 -1 = 99
> - Engineer = 100 -1 -1 = 98
> - Staff = 100

4.sort your items by weight:

> - Staff (100)
> - IT (99)|Teacher (99)
> - Engineer (98)